# jQuery 1.5 doesn't work on IE 9 RC

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-1.5

Internet Explorer RC 9 was released earlier today, but I can't get it to work with jQuery 1.5. It stops at this error:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagName' 
jquery.min.js, line 16 character 59007
```

**Edit:** I found this bug @ http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8052

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [jQuery bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8052) about the issue. It's fixed already and coming to the next release.